# saving multiples foreign key in laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here's my situation:

In my controller, i need save two foreign keys: `exam_id` and `category_id`, but always say:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'exam_id' doesn't have a default value`

The context:
Exam have a questions (Exam hasMany question but question belongs to Exam). Also Question belongs to category, and Category hasMany questions. In the model looks like

`Category`

```
class Category extends Model{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name'
    ];
    
    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
}
```

`Exam`

```
class Exam extends Model{
    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'title', 'description', 'score'
    ];
    protected $guarded = [];
    
    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function questions(){
        return $this->hasMany(Question::class);
    }
}
```

`Question`

```
class Question extends Model{
     protected $fillable = [
         'exam_id', 'category_id' ,'description', 'iframe', 'image',
     ];

     protected $guarded = [];

     public function exam(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Exam::class, 'exam_id');
     }

     public function category(){
         return $this->belongsTo(Category::class);
     }
}
```

QuestionController

```
public function store(QuestionStoreRequest $request){
        $questions = Question::create($request->all());
        $questions->exam()->attach($request->get('exam_id'));
        $questions->category()->attach($request->get('category_id'));

        $questions->save();

        return view('question.create');
    }
```

When i try save on my store method, never insert field `exam_id` and idk why? How save multiples foreign key?

**UPDATE 1:**

I add how declare my tables (and relations)

```
+----+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | user_id | title          | description                    | score | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 | Primer examen  | Examen de testing              |   100 | 2020-07-31 05:26:31 | 2020-07-31 05:26:31 |
|  4 |       1 | Segundo examen | Descripcion del segundo examen |   100 | 2020-08-04 21:10:18 | 2020-08-04 21:10:18 |
+----+---------+----------------+--------------------------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+

 select * from questions;
+----+---------+-------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | exam_id | category_id | description                   | iframe               | image | order | created_at          | updated_at          |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |       1 |           1 | ¿Capital de mexico?           | algo nomas de prueba | NULL  |  NULL | 2020-08-06 06:45:50 | 2020-08-06 06:45:50 |
|  2 |       1 |           2 | ¿Capital de Rusia?            | algo nomas de prueba | NULL  |  NULL | 2020-08-06 06:54:39 | 2020-08-06 06:54:39 |
|  3 |       4 |           1 | ¿Hoy es viernes, loremp ipsu? | algo nomas de prueba | NULL  |  NULL | 2020-08-06 06:58:18 | 2020-08-06 06:58:18 |
+----+---------+-------------+-------------------------------+----------------------+-------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

And when i insert a question, the question insert the exam_id.

What I'm trying to do is, when I insert the question, it should take the id of the exam it belongs to. I don't know if this should be saved in the Question controller or should be saved in the Exam controller.

**UPDATE 3:**

the dd() output:

```
array:4 [▼
  "_token" => "ec4qvPN6hySporQUvZrnAIqkmZEOCvAMLFAUQB6q"
  "description" => "igdiysagdfyud"
  "iframe" => "iysgdfygsdyufgsdf"
  "category" => "3"
]
```

**UPDATE 4**

Question form (get the category_id)

```
<form action="/questions" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    @CSRF
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Descripcion de la pregunta*</label>
        <textarea name="description" type="text"
                  class="form-control" id="description"
                  aria-describedby="descriptionHelp"
                  placeholder="Inserte la pregunta">{{ old('description') }}</textarea>
        <small id="descriptionHelp"
               class="form-text text-muted">Escribe la descripcion de la pregunta.</small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="iframe">Video asociado *</label>
        <textarea name="iframe" type="text"
                  class="form-control" id="iframe"
                  aria-describedby="iframeHelp"
                  placeholder="Inserte la URL del video">{{ old('iframe') }}</textarea>
        <small id="iframeHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Inserta la url del video.</small>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group d-flex flex-column">
        <label for="image">Imagen asociada</label>
        <input name="image" type="file" class="py-1">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="category">A que categoria pertenece</label>
        <select name="category" class="form-control form-control-lg" id="category">
            @foreach($category as $category)
                <option value="{{ $category->id }}">{{ $category->name }}</option>
            @endforeach
        </select>
        <small id="selectHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Elige una categoria.</small>
    </div>
    <hr />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar pregunta</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The `attach()` method is for a many-to-many relationship (via `belongsToMany()`). None of your relationships use this logic...

Comment: When  use associate(), get the same error, example: `$questions->exam()->associate('exam_id);`

Comment: I don't think you need to call that at all; `Question::create()` will auto-associate to Exam and Category via those columns. Remove both your attach calls and your save call and see if it works.

Comment: Okya, i'm try  your comment.

Comment: Nice! But you can see that you're missing the `exam_id` and `category_id` fields. Where is that data coming from? And HTML Form? And Ajax request? Somewhere along the line, you're missing those fields, and if they never make it to the database, you won't be able to save `null` into those columns.

Comment: The exam_id field I try to obtain through the store method, and for category_id show my html..

Comment: There's no `exam_id` (or `exam`) field in your HTML form. You need to allow the user to select the exam they want for association and send that to your controller. I'm not sure what this "store method" you're referring to is, but regardless; you're trying to assign a property that you're not sending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why not use direct properties?

```
public function store(QuestionStoreRequest $request){
        $questions =new  Question();
        $questions->description=$request->get('description');
        $questions->iframe=$request->get('iframe');
        $questions->image=$request->get('image');
        $questions->exam_id=$request->get('exam_id');
        $questions->category_id=$request->get('category_id');
        $questions->save();
        return view('question.create');
    }
```

this way, you go to db once, not three times

Comment: you are right, i have edited my answer to be more clear

Comment: This is the more verbose approach (and is perfectly acceptable), but I think that `Question::create($request->all());`, and removing the additional logic (including save, etc) would have worked just fine :)

Comment: I use your answer but i have a new error (yeah!) `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'exam_id' cannot be null` why?

Comment: @Edgar Gc that means $request->get('exam_id') is null

Comment: @Tim Lewis you absolutely right, i made that step on purpose so the error would be more clearer

Comment: @OMR Haha yeah, no worries :) if `exam_id` is `null` from `$request`, that's an entirely different issue than syntax preference, so good call on separating that.

Comment: Oh, i think need more information about mi database, right? Ok, update my question.

Comment: @EdgarGc Not more information about your DB, but rather your HTML form or Ajax request; where is `$request->get('exam_id')` coming from, and why would it be `null`

Comment: @EdgarGc please try dd($request->all()) what the output?

Comment: @TimLewis i add the dd output.

Comment: there is no 'exam_id' in your request inputs,
also you should rename the input (category) to (category_id)

Comment: so, first i need get the exam_id, right. The idea is Exam->have question-> in question have crud for questions (like /exam/id/question/creat) and get the exam_id.

Comment: not exactly, in your QuestionStoreRequest set the rules array so the category_id and exam_id are reqiured